# Is possible to use PHQL in a non PhalconPHP project?

Tags: php, phalcon

So this is my question. I have a legacy project with more than 700K PHP lines. Homemade framework.

Our ORM works, but I'd like to try the PhalconPHP in the project.

We are using Pimple as DI.

Is it possible to run just the Model/PHQL in a non Phalcon project?

If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Thanks to @calin in the [PhalconPHP forum](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/6495/phql-in-a-non-phalcon-project) I found the answer. Basically the steps are the following ones:

1. Create an instance of the Phalcon DI (or any that extends the DI interface)
2. Set the modelsManager
3. Set the modelsMetadata
4. Set the db
5. Set the default DI
6. In the model, define the getSource if necessary.

Example:

```
<?php

$di = new \Phalcon\DI();
$di->set('modelsManager', function () {
    return new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager();
});
$di->set('modelsMetadata', function () {
    return new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData\Memory();
});
$di->set('db', function () {
    return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
        'adapter' => 'Mysql',
        'host' => 'xxx.dev',
        'username' => 'xxxx',
        'password' => 'yyy',
        'dbname' => 'zzz',
    ));
});

\Phalcon\DI::setDefault($di);
```

That has to be called in some part before you will need the call to the Models/PHQL.

Define a normal Model, and call the models. It's pretty epic.

Model example:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\App\Mvc\Model;

use \Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{

    public function getSource()
    {
        return "users";
    }
}
```

And in some part of the code, after the calls to the Phalcon DI:

```
<?php

 echo \Vendor\App\Mvc\Model\UserModel::find()->count();
```